# Get data attribute onchange event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom-events

I'm trying to retrieve a custom data attribute that I did add to the option element, but it's not working.

```
<p>Select a new car from the list.</p>

<select id="mySelect" onchange="myFunction(this.data-price)">
  <option data-price="250" value="Audi">Audi</option>
  <option data-price="130" value="BMW">BMW</option>
  <option data-price="120" value="Mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option data-price="400" value="Volvo">Volvo</option>
</select>

<p>When you select a new car, a function is triggered which outputs the value of the selected car.</p>
<p id="demo"></p>
```

```
function myFunction(val) {
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "You selected: " + val;
  console.log(val);
}
```

The thing is when I switch the function call to:

```
onchange="myFunction(this.value)">
```

It returns the value correctly, but when I select the data-price, it returns `undefined` to the console.

Comment: That is not correct.... `this.data-price` is saying `this.data minus price`, that is NOT how you read data attributes

Comment: @coderHelper i tried it returns the full select element !

Comment: @epascarello how should i then?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code is saying "get data property" and subtract a variable "price" from it. Second issue, you are selecting the property on the select when it lives on the option. You can not act use it like value.

You should be using [dataset](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes) on the selected option

```js
function myFunction(sel) {
  var opt = sel.options[sel.selectedIndex];
  var price = opt.dataset.price
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "You selected: " + price;
}
```

```html
<p>Select a new car from the list.</p>

<select id="mySelect" onchange="myFunction(this)">
  <option data-price="250" value="Audi">Audi</option>
  <option data-price="130" value="BMW">BMW</option>
  <option data-price="120" value="Mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option data-price="400" value="Volvo">Volvo</option>
</select>

<p>When you select a new car, a function is triggered which outputs the value of the selected car.</p>
<p id="demo"></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply access the data attribute of the selected option (jQuery example since you tagged it):

```js
$("#mySelect").change(function() {
  const $this = $(this); // Cache $(this)
  const dataVal = $this.find(':selected').data('price'); // Get data value
  const selectedVal = $this[0].value;
  alert(`${dataVal}, ${selectedVal}`);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>Select a new car from the list.</p>

<select id="mySelect">
  <option data-price="250" value="Audi">Audi</option>
  <option data-price="130" value="BMW">BMW</option>
  <option data-price="120" value="Mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option data-price="400" value="Volvo">Volvo</option>
</select>

<p>When you select a new car, a function is triggered which outputs the value of the selected car.</p>
<p id="demo"></p>
```

Comment: @coderHelper It produces an error because you inlined your js function call (never do that). I've removed it, and it no longer produces an error.

Comment: The thing is i didn't want to try this one with jquery is because i have a form repeater and this one will only select the first form . The added ones won't trigger any event . It's only available to the first element(the one i get duplicates from)

Comment: @ZakariaSichaib, then why did you tag jQuery? Also, this will work _perfectly_ with your form repeater. Simply change the selector to a class selector: `$(".myCustomClassSelectorForAllDropDowns").change(function() { ... }`. You don't need to inline your JS for this to work.